# separate $value in an array for create a $key => $value array

Tags: php, arrays, key, explode

I may not be clear enough in the title but here is my problem.

I have a string like this

```
$chain = "id:20604#*#user_id:32444#*#session_id:0#*#version:142#*#modified:1438610605#*#name:recrutement#*#push:0#*#last_push_execution:0#*#allowempty:1";
```

I do an `explode("#*#", $chain);`
and now i have this:

```
array:9 [
  0 => "id:20604"
  1 => "user_id:32444"
  2 => "session_id:0"
  3 => "version:142"
  4 => "modified:1438610605"
  5 => "name:recrutement"
  6 => "push:0"
  7 => "last_push_execution:0"
  8
```

]

But i wanna something like this

```
array:9 [
  "id" => "20604"
  "user_id" => "32444"
  "session_id" => "0"
  "version" => "142"
  "modified" => "1438610605"
  "name" => "recrutement"
  "push"=> "0"
  "last_push_execution"=> "0"
  ]
```

Can anyone show me how to do it ?

thanks

Comment: You should use a standardized data format like json or serialize. Then you don't have to parse it manually with all the potential problems that will introduce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Simple solution using `explode` function:

```
$chain = "id:20604#*#user_id:32444#*#session_id:0#*#version:142#*#modified:1438610605#*#name:recrutement#*#push:0#*#last_push_execution:0#*#allowempty:1";
$result = [];

foreach (explode("#*#", $chain) as $c) {
    $pair = explode(":", $c);
    $result[$pair[0]] = $pair[1];
}
```

2) Alternative solution using `preg_match_all` and `array_combine` functions:

```
$chain = "id:20604#*#user_id:32444#*#session_id:0#*#version:142#*#modified:1438610605#*#name:recrutement#*#push:0#*#last_push_execution:0#*#allowempty:1";
preg_match_all("/\b(\w+):(\w+)\b/", $chain, $matches);
$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Both approaches will give the needed result

Comment: @BarbeBleue, you're welcome

Answer (score 2):

One way to rome.

```
$final=array();
array_map(
    function($a) use (&$final){
      list($k,$v)=explode(':',$a);  
      $final[$k]=$v;
    },
    explode("#*#", $chain)
);
var_export($final);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using PHP's [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) method like this:

```
$arr = [
  0 => "id:20604",
  1 => "user_id:32444",
  2 => "session_id:0",
  3 => "version:142",
  4 => "modified:1438610605",
  5 => "name:recrutement",
  6 => "push:0",
  7 => "last_push_execution:0",
];

$final_arr = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
    $a = explode(':', $val);
    $final_arr[$a[0]] = $a[1];
}
```

The final output would be:

```
$final_arr = array:8 [
  "id" => "20604"
  "user_id" => "32444"
  "session_id" => "0"
  "version" => "142"
  "modified" => "1438610605"
  "name" => "recrutement"
  "push" => "0"
  "last_push_execution" => "0"
]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst `array_map()` is a more elegant solution, this is an alternative :

```
$outArray = array();
$tempArray = explode("#*#", $chain);
foreach ($tempArray as $chainValue) {
  $split = explode(':',$chainValue);
  $key = $split[0];
  $value = $split[1];
  $outArray[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply